# How to put constraints on the associated data?

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

I would like to state that the associated data is always an instance of a certain class.

```
class (Context (Associated a b)) => Class a where
  data Associated a :: * -> *

instance Context (Associated a b) where
  func1 = error "func1"
```

However, the free variable `b` that is not in scope prevents me from this. One of the solutions is to copy class functions from `Context`, but it looks ugly.

```
class Class a where
  data Associated a :: * -> *
  -- duplicate all functions from class Context
  contextFunc1 :: Associated a b -> String

instance Class a => Context (Associated a b) where
  func1 = contextFunc1
```

Is there an idiomatic way to put constraints on associated data type which has variables not mentioned in head?

edit: I would like to keep compatibility with GHC 7.0.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have GHC 7.0.3 available, but I think this should work with it.

You could pass the dictionaries around manually like this (using `Context` = `Show` as an example):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShowDict a = Show a => ShowDict

class Class a where
  data Associated a :: * -> *

  getShow :: ShowDict (Associated a b)

-- Convenience function
getShowFor :: Class a => Associated a b -> ShowDict (Associated a b)
getShowFor _ = getShow

showAssociated :: Class a => Associated a b -> String
showAssociated a = 
  case getShowFor a of
    ShowDict -> -- Show (Associated a b) is made available by this pattern match 
      show a

instance Class Int where
  data Associated Int b = Foo deriving Show

  getShow = ShowDict

main = print $ showAssociated Foo
```

This is somewhat similar to the function copying you propose, but advantages are:

- Avoids repetition (of `Context`'s method signatures)
- Having `Show Baz` in context is somewhat more powerful than just having a function for showing a `Baz`, since it allows you to call (library) functions which require `Show Baz`, or use implied instances like `Show [Baz]`:

```
showAssociateds :: forall a b. Class a => [Associated a b] -> String
showAssociateds as = 
  case getShow :: ShowDict (Associated a b) of
    ShowDict ->
      show as
```

The main disadvantage is that using `getShow` always requires an explicit type signature (functions like `getShowFor` can mitigate this).

Answer (score 6):

*As was [pointed out by @SjoerdVisscher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258536/how-to-put-constraints-on-the-associated-data/11259706#comment14823576_11259706), using `forall` on the left side of `=>` in a `class` or `instance` [is actually **not** ok](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7019#comment:3), at least not yet, though my specific example does work in ghc-7.4.*

---

This way it seems to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Context c where
  func1 :: c -> String

class (forall b. Context (Associated a b)) => Class a where
  data Associated a :: * -> *

newtype ClassTest = ClassTest { runClassTest :: String }

instance (forall b. Context (Associated ClassTest b)) => Class ClassTest where
  data Associated ClassTest b = ClassTestAssoc b (b -> ClassTest)

instance Context (Associated ClassTest b) where
  func1 (ClassTestAssoc b strFunc) = runClassTest $ strFunc b

main = putStr . func1 $ ClassTestAssoc 37 (ClassTest . show)
```

The extra `forall b` constraint in the instance seems a bit ugly and redundant, but apparently it's necessary.

> $ runghc-7.4.1 tFamConstraint0.hs
>   37

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately lack of compatibility with GHC 7.0 would be a serious drawback for me because this code will be used in a library. But I like the solution and I would use it when GHC 7.4+ becomes ubiquitous.

Comment: If you want maximum compatibility, your probably better off with stupidly copying all class methods, even though it is a bit awkward.

Comment: @leftaroundabout SPJ says this shouldn't work: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7019#comment:3

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: thanks! I don't understand much about the implementation issues, but it seems to me that this quantified contexts stuff is in principle desirable and might at some point work properly, so I'll leave the answer here with a warning message; or do you think that's inappropriate?

Comment: Using [`Data.Constraint.Forall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html): you can write `class ForallF Context (Associated a) => Class a`

as well as
`instance ForallF Context (Associated ClassTest) => Class ClassTest`

Answer (score 1):

One idiomatic way is to create a `Context1` class. Supposing we have

```
class Context a where
    func :: a -> String
```

we might generalize as:

```
class Context1 f where
    func1 :: Context a => f a -> String
```

Then you give a single instance for all `Associated`s:

```
instance (Context1 (Associated a), Context b) => Context (Associated a b) where
    func = func1
```

Now it is easy to write the class you want as

```
instance Context1 (Associated a) => Class a where
    data Associated a :: * -> *
```

and you can be sure that the given `Context1 (Associated a)` context ensures the desired `forall b. Context b => Context (Associated a b)` context.

There are many examples of this pattern on Hackage, like [Show1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Show1), [Foldable1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.0.0.3/docs/Data-Semigroup-Foldable.html#t:Foldable1), and [Traversable1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversable1).