# Type variable is not in scope when defining type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm writing a type class à la mtl-style transformers. Looks like this:

```
class (Monad m, Stream s m t) => MonadStuff s m | m -> s where
  -- function signatures go here…
```

I'm trying to say by that that `m` should be instance of `Monad` and there
should be instance of `Stream s m t`, where `t` doesn't really matter but
`s` and `m` are from the right side of the definition (after `=>`).

Haskell says:

> Not in scope: type variable ‘t’

So, obviously I cannot do that. Or can I? Should I remove `Stream s m t`
constraint and add it to every function in the class instead or is there
another way?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Stream) class from parsec, why not just add `t` to `MonadStuff`? `class Stream s m t => MonadStuff s t m | m -> s, s -> t`

Comment: @Cirdec, Not exactly from Parsec, but thanks for the advice anyway. Solution from linked answer is rather ugly.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as the [claimed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258536/) is about demanding `forall a. Constraint (Foo a)` rather than `forall a. Constraint Foo a`, which seem fundamentally different to me.

Comment: Can you show us what the methods of your class look like? Perhaps it is possible to move the `Stream m s t` constraint into the method signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's really true that it doesn't really matter what `t` is, then perhaps you can ask the person writing the instance to choose it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class (Monad m, Stream s m (StuffType m)) => MonadStuff s m | m -> s where
    type StuffType m
```

Or, since you already have MPTCs and fundeps turned on, you could consider doing this, which requires no extra extensions but is otherwise basically identical:

```
class (Monad m, Stream s m t) => MonadStuff s m t | m -> s t where
```

However, I am suspicious that in fact the choice of `t` *does* matter: unless `Stream` has a fundep that is at least as informative as `m s -> t`, you will not be able to *use* this constraint in a meaningful way. In that case, you should move the constraint into the signatures of the methods that mention `t` or will be using the `Stream` methods.

Comment: `Stream s m t` has fundep `s -> t`. However it was getting hairy in a way and I've simplified it to `Stream s t` so I ended up using `class (Monad m, Stream s t) => MonadStuff s m t | m -> s t where`. This seems to work.